# To factor code in function or not?

Tags: c++, function, coding-style

A little question that I know many diverge on this but I would like to know performance and sanity wise, what do you use to do:

**What's best, factoring code in function (when using the same piece of code in multiple places) but then having to face the function-call cost or just keeping those pieces everywhere then having to deal with changes in different places when you have to change the logic?
Considering the fact that I need my code to be the fastest possible. Because it will run on memory/cpu restricted device.**

Maybe some of you have a rule of thumb they apply, like when the code is bigger than a certain amount of lign, they gather it in a function...

Comment: I've flagged the post for closure as it's going to be too opinion-based. That being said, here's mine: Refactoring code into functions is generally a better idea for reuse and to have only a single location to modify when fixing bugs. On the other hand, one reason I've read about for avoiding this is to prevent coupling of modules/units that are required to be completely separate.

Comment: If the function is small, and having multiple copies of the code is an advantage, the compiler will inline the function anyway.

Comment: @ray I think also that the answer is subjective but it also depends of the experience of each one. And that's what I want to know, when is one solution better than the other?

Comment: But *that's* the problem; whether a solution is "better" than the other is completely subjective, so you can't expect to find out which one's really "better" unless you share a very specific case for us to consider. The generic and non-specific nature of the question will simply attract responses that are unlikely to be useful because they'll likely be one-size-fits-all type proposals --which can create more problems than actual solutions. This question is best evaluated on a case-by-case basis. Do you have a *specific case* that you can share?

Comment: @BoPersson: But that's still factoring the code into a function. The OP doesn't seem to be asking about getting the compiler to do its magic, but rather, on having the programmer manually duplicating code, etc.

Comment: Code duplication increases load on the CPU cache. You can't simply say whether functions are fast or slow without measurements.

Comment: @BoPersson: True, but I'm not sure I follow. I never said that he/she should be duplicating code to save on function call costs, etc.

Comment: Yes my concern is about the cost of the function-call when you need fast code like for real time simulation. But I think I have a good picture of your opinion about it => use function anytime a code is in more than 1 place.

Comment: Having mutliple small functions is better: https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/the-real-benefits-of-short-methods/

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, I realized that afterwards. My bad :)

Answer (score 4):

Rule of thumb:

- Trust the compiler, in general it has better heuristics than you whether a code should be inlined. Write clean code. Code duplication is your enemy.
- Measure the performance or check the generated code, and only try to optimize if you are unhappy with the results.
- If there are problems, try to utilize templates to avoid code duplication and generate code at the template instantiation location.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback